# Не отправляется сообщение при запросе

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я хотел сделать, чтобы при ответе "Да" в моем коде отправлялось сообщение, но оно не отправляется. Батник (сервер, через которого я запускаю бота) ошибки не выдает:

```py
    import telebot
    import config
    from telebot import types
    
    client = telebot.TeleBot(config.token['token'])
    
    
    @client.message_handler(commands = ['info', 'get_info'])
    def user_info(message):
        markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        types_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'да', callback_data = 'yes')
        types_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'нет', callback_data = 'no')
    
        markup_inline.add(types_yes, types_no)
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здравствуйте, вас привествует бот Зэт, желаете увидеть прайс лист?',
            reply_markup = markup_inline
        )
    
    @client.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
    def answer(call):
        if call.data == 'yes':
            markup_inline2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
            item_tg = types.KeyboardButton('Telegram')
            item_ds = types.KeyboardButton('Disscord')
            item_vk = types.KeyboardButton('VK')
            item_s = types.KeyboardButton('Special')
    
            markup_inline2.add(item_tg, item_vk, item_ds, item_s)
            client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Telegram - 50$; VK - недоступно; Disscord - недоступно. P.S:Для спец. заказов сюда - @s1renhead',
                reply_markup = markup_inline2
            )
    
    client.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Comment: Вы пробовали в `answer` вместо `call` использовать `message` и  заменить `call.data` на `message.text`? И дам вам небольшой совет , используйте метод `.lower` по отношению к тексту сообщения , который будете обрабатывать

Comment: @shalor1k Все равно не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ловите CallbackQuery

```
@client.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
```

поэтому получать данные надо оттуда же. Т.е. брать не `message.chat.id`, а `call.message.chat.id`. Для вашего кода:

```
client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Telegram - 50$; VK - недоступно; Disscord - недоступно. P.S:Для спец. заказов сюда - @s1renhead',
            reply_markup = markup_inline2
        )
```

UPDATE (не верный тип кнопок):
Измените тип кнопок в этом коде:

```
markup_inline2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
            item_tg = types.KeyboardButton('Telegram')
            item_ds = types.KeyboardButton('Disscord')
            item_vk = types.KeyboardButton('VK')
            item_s = types.KeyboardButton('Special')
```

на этот:

```
item_ds = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Disscord', callback_data='Disscord')
item_vk = types.InlineKeyboardButton('VK', callback_data='VK')
item_s = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Special', callback_data='Special')

markup_inline2.row(item_tg, item_vk, item_ds, item_s)
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, в чем ещё может быть причина

Comment: Понял, у вас не те кнопки для клавиатуры. Нужно заменить             item_tg =  
types.KeyboardButton('Telegram')
            item_ds = types.KeyboardButton('Disscord')
            item_vk = types.KeyboardButton('VK')
            item_s = types.KeyboardButton('Special') на types.InlineKeyboardButton

Comment: Все равно, выдает ошибку в роде NameError: name 'InlineKeyboardMarkup' is not defined

Comment: Кароче как итог, я вернул все как было сначала и просто в место markup_repli.add поставил markup_reply.row и все зароботало

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```py
@client.message_handler(content_types= ["text"])
def answer(message):
    if message.text == 'yes':
        #далее ваш код
        #и всё же вернуть message.chat.id
```

Comment: В данном случаи мне сервер не выдает ошибку, но сообщение все ещё не отправляеться

Comment: @Clear360 Я конечно извиняюсь , но может вы случайно боту отправляете вместо "yes" , "Yes"?И попробуйте добавить `else` , чтобы понять обрабатывает ли он в целом ваше сообщение

Comment: Вот так?

  markup_inline2.add(item_tg, item_vk, item_ds, item_s)
  client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Telegram - 50$; VK - недоступно; Disscord - недоступно. P.S:Для спец. заказов сюда - @s1renhead',
   reply_markup = markup_inline2
  )
 else:
  client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'No')

Comment: @Clear360 Да, всё верно